# add_filter multiple times with different addon functions?

Tags: filters

I'm adding this filter when the condition is true. Can I add another function on the same filter when the 2nd condition is true or will the last one cancel out the previous one?

```
if(get_option('my_nofollow_flag'){
    add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 'save_add_nofollow' );
}

if(get_option('my_second_option'){
    add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 'another_function' );
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Hi **@Scott B:**

Absolutely. That's part of the design of the system, you can add as many as you need *(other plugins do.)*

The only issue is if you might need to address which one runs first and that's when you may have to set the *priority.*  In the below example the third one would run first and the second one would run last:

```
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data','norm_priority_func'); // 10=default priority 
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data','run_last_funcn', 11 );  
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data','run_first_func', 9 );
```

Of course when you have needs to set priorities you can find it may cause conflict with other plugins that set a priority higher or lower. Typical places where this happens is when you want a hook to run either before or after all others. Are 0 and 100 sufficient priorities?  Not if another plugin used -1 and 101; see the quandry? Anyway, that's usually not an issue but when it is, it is.